# How to handle inner functions in qunit

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, qunit

I just started with Qunit, and don't know much about it.

The problem I'm having is that I have written this function in my code and want to test this using Qunit.

```
  <script>
    function calc(firstno,secnum){
       return firstno + secnum;
     }

   function main (firstno,secnum){

    return  calc(firstno,secnum);

    }


 </script>
```

So, how should I test the `calc` function when I write a test case for the `main` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
test('Testing that main adds numbers', function() {
    var a = 1;
    var b = 3;

    var result = main(a, b);
    equal(4, result, 'Main adds two numbers together');
});
```

When you are testing `main()`, you are not concerned that it calls `calc()` only that it returns two numbers added together.

In your example, you would likely have a separate test for `calc()` as it is publicly available. And this way you are saying that you have functions `main` and `calc`.

You are testing the behavior of the code rather than the actual implementation.  The fact that `main` calls `calc` is not what you are trying to test.  Only what the actual return of `main` is.

Comment: What happens if the inner function has mockable stuffs. Wont it be failed?

Comment: @Jagan then you could create a double that gets injected into the code.  However this should be reserved for external actions (AJAX calls, 3rd Party API's, etc).  You are not specifying how the code performs its action.  You are specifying what the action is.